# VBA: Macro to copy and paste values into an offset cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am a not so great at VBA, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I want to make a macro which copies a value from a cell.

**There is then a drop down list with a set of dates that you can choose from.**

Depending on the date you choose, the macro will paste the value onto an offset cell.

```
Public Sub Paste_Values_Examples()

    Dim rgFound As Range
    Set rgFound = Range("A3:Z3").Find("J36")
    
    Range("J29").Value = Range("rgFound.Address").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End Sub
```

Here is a slightly simplified version. Any ideas guys? :)

Comment: Try to be precise in your question, that makes it easier to read. So "a cell", what cell exactly? "a set of dates", please provide examples. "an offset cell" what offset, why an offset?

Comment: Also you are not stating what is wrong with your code, does it work, but not correctly? doesn't do anything at all?

Comment: Now sure what you're doing, but the line before the `End Sub` should be: `Range("J29").Value = rgFound.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` or at least, `Range("J29").Value = Range(rgFound.Address).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`